# Time zone for china not working in python arrow

Tags: python, datetime, python-arrow

```
arrow.get('2016-01-01')
arrow.get(datetime.now(), 'US/Pacific')

arrow.get(datetime.now(), 'China')
arrow.get(datetime.now(), 'CT')
arrow.get(datetime.now(), 'CST')
```

So, the first two statements work, but the remaining 3 which are trying to convert time to China time do not. How do I fix this?

Comment: According to the Arrow docs at https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, Arrow uses the timezone names in the tz database. Those names can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Asia/Shanghai` or zh-cn as a timezones string.

Comment: `zh-cn` not work